# MySQL int Column Mapping to Int64. How can I make it map to Int32 (ie. int)?

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, mysql-connector, edmx

I have the following table in my MySQL database:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `full_name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `ip_address` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `joined_unix` int(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `avatar` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bio` text,
  `email_confirmed` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `email_confirmation_security_hash` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_notification_time` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `last_login_unix` int(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `admin` int(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `SecurityStamp` longtext,
  `PhoneNumber` longtext,
  `PhoneNumberConfirmed` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `TwoFactorEnabled` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `LockoutEndDateUtc` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `LockoutEnabled` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `AccessFailedCount` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`),
  KEY `Joined unix for stats page` (`joined_unix`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3035 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I notice that my `id` column maps to `Int64` within my EDMX file and if I change it, queries throw an exception even though the EDMX validates successfully.

How can I make it map to just `int` (`Int32`) instead of Int64?

Comment: The choice of int(10) seems deliberate, based on your other int variables.  If you need this magnitude I'm afraid you're stuck with Int64/long

Comment: This is what I find very strange.  I have changed it to `Int(8)` as a test (Also in all related tables) and regenerating a new EDMX also maps the column to long `Int64`?  Any more ideas?

Comment: Ahh no it didn't!  I removed my connection string and regenerated it and it then it was happy with that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number (e.g., 10) after any integer data type has *nothing* to do with the data the column can contain in MySQL.  That number is known as the "display width."

> The display width does not constrain the range of values that can be stored in the column.
>
> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/numeric-type-attributes.html

It's a legacy feature from the days of fixed-character-width terminals that an application could use as a "hint" of the widest value that should be expected, and nothing more.  If what you're using is actually using that information for something else, then that's broken behavior.

An `INT UNSIGNED` can hold any 32 bit unsigned integer -- values between between 0 and 2^32-1, regardless of the display width in the column definition.

If you have a system that doesn't deal with 32 bit unsigned integers, but you really wany to use that 32 bit data type, you should declare the column as `INT`, which is a signed 32 bit integer, with the accompanying smaller range on either side of zero, instead of `INT UNSIGNED`.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/integer-types.html